# reseting y position of an element in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

i have a canvas who is tweening upwards by a button click.
I am trying to make it go back down after the tween is over, but it just does'nt work.
It starts off fine at the top of the screen. the first time i click the button it does go down to 400, and then slides up to 200. but on the next click - it would just keep flying up, instead of going back to 400 first.
Please help! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <script src=
    "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="func();">click</button> <canvas height="100" id="canvas"
    style="position:absolute; top:50px; border:3px solid #000000;" width=
    "200"></canvas> 
    <script>
           var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
            function func(){             
                c.style.top = 400 + "px";
                TweenMax.to(c,2,{y: "-=200", onComplete:foo});
            }
            function foo(){
              c.style.top = "400px";
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`c.style.top` have nothing to do with `y` modifications from TweenMax once the tweening happened. On a first call of `TweenMax.to`, TweenMax creates a transform matrix (custom style) on the object, and stops paying attention to regular css properties from this point on.

You have to define `startAt: {y: '400px'}` in your `.to` call to force TweenMax to reset tweening to a static value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that that this tweening plug-in actually changes `transform` CSS property to make the transition. Thus, make any changes in elements' `style.top` won't affect its position, as it is overrode by TweenMax's, browser-specific, `transform`.

You can use their `startAt` property to always start at the desired position. I don't recommend this plug-in though, I personally prefer [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TyZhB/2/

Comment: I wouldn't call it "stupid". It's heavily optimized for speed, and it's inevitable that some corners will be cut in the process. Although JS speed optimizations at the cost of code quality are becoming more and more redundant nowadays.

Comment: Yes, maybe I was to harsh, but seeing that the problem was that the script changes `-webkit-transform` property just to move a box 200px higher seemed so wrong... It's like you either use **only** this TweenMax with no `CSS`, or you don't use it at all